# How can I prove that $A_1^c, A_2,A_3,A_4,\dots,A_n$ are independent events

Tags: probability

Given $A_1,A_2,\dots,A_n$ are independent events, To prove(correct me if I am wrong) for $n$ events $A_1^c,A_2,A_3,\dots,A_n$ are mutually independent we need to check the following conditions:

1. $P(A_1^c\cap A_2) = P(A_1^c)\cdot P(A_2)$

   $P(A_1^c\cap A_3) = P(A_1^c)\cdot P(A_3)$

   and so on until:

   $P(A_1^c\cap A_3) = P(A_1^c)\cdot P(A_n)$
2. $P(A_1^c\cap A_2\cap A_3\cap\dots\cap A_n) = P(A_1^c)\cdot P(A_2)\cdot P(A_3)\cdot \ldots \cdot P(A_n)$
3. $P(A_1^c\cap A_2\cap A_4)$

   $P(A_1^c\cap A_2\cap A_5)$

   $P(A_1^c\cap A_2\cap A_n)$

   $P(A_1^c\cap A_3\cap A_8)$

   $P(A_1^c\cap A_2\cap A_3\cap A_5)$

   and so on until each and every intersection is included

I have made proven the 1st and 2nd condition in [image: Here]
My question: How does one generalize the 3rd condition so that it is not required to prove it rigorously

Comment: Wait so you want to prove independence of $A_1^C, A_2, ..., A_n$ given independence of $A_1, A_2, ..., A_n$ ?

Comment: yes exactly but i dont know what notations am i supposed to use to generalize the 3rd part?

Answer (score 1):

Do induction.

For n=1, show that if $A_1$ is independent of itself, then $A_1^c$ is independent of itself. (Fun fact: The following 3 conditions are equivalent: $A$ is independent of itself. $P(A)=0$ or $1$. $A$ is independent of every other event $B$.)

For n=2, show that if $A_1,A_2$ are independent, then $A_1^c,A_2$ are independent.

Now you probably have a feel of what's going on. Otherwise continue n=3 and n=4.

Now for induction.

1. Assume that the independence of $A_1, A_2..., A_k$ implies independence of $A_1^c, A_2..., A_k$.
2. Assume the independence of $A_1, A_2..., A_k, A_{k+1}$.
3. Prove the independence of $A_1^c, A_2..., A_k, A_{k+1}$.

Comment: but how would you prove(or more correctly, what notation should i use to prove) the k-wise independent for example: P(A1c∩A2∩A5), P(A1c∩A2∩A3∩A5), etc? given that they are not in sequence with each other

Comment: @JeffreyAnders Oh, good question. I think I see what you mean. $k$-wise independence is when you take $k$ events at a time right? I guess prove that $P(A_1^c, A_2, ..., A_k)$ splits up and that $P(A_2, ..., A_k, A_{k+1})$ splits up and then....hmmm......ok so it's like this prove that $P(A_1^c, A_3, ..., A_k, A_{k+1})$ splits up, that $P(A_1^c, A_2, A_4..., A_k, A_{k+1})$ splits up, that $P(A_1^c, A_2, A_3, A_5, ..., A_k, A_{k+1})$ splits up, etc. In general prove that $P(A_1^c, A_2, ..., A_{i-1}, A_{i+1}, ..., A_k, A_{k+1})$ splits up, where $i$ is from 3 to $k-1$

Comment: yes yes exactly!