# Proving $A_1^c,A_2, ... ,A_n$ are independent.

Tags: probability, solution-verification, independence

Let $A_1,\ldots, A_n$ be independent events. Prove $A_1^c,A_2,\ldots, A_n$ are independent as well.

---

So I wish to reference a question posted by **Jeffrey Anders**: [How can I prove that $A_1^c, A_2,A_3,A_4,\dots,A_n$ are independent events](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4061160/how-can-i-prove-that-a-1c-a-2-a-3-a-4-dots-a-n-are-independent-events) and more specifically an answer given by **BCLC**.

---

I've proven the base of my induction and am now stuck in the step. I assume $A_1^c,A_2,\ldots, A_{n-1}$ are independent, knowing $A_1,\ldots, A_n$ are independent from the datum.

Now from the assumption: $$\forall I \in [n-1]: P(\cap_{i\in I}A_i)=P(\Pi_{i \in I}A_i)$$

Therefore assume $I \in [n]$. Now I have:$$P(\cap_{i\in I}A_i)=P(\cap_{i \in I \setminus\{n,1\}}A_i \cap A_n \cap A_1^c)$$

I want to say: $\cap_{i \in I \setminus\{n,1\}}A_i \cap A_n$ is independent from the datum, and $\cap_{i \in I \setminus\{n,1\}}A_i \cap A_1^c$ is independent form the assumption of the induction.

Now denote:

$$P(A_1^c \cap A_n) = P(A_n)-P(A_1 \cap A_n)=P(A_n)-P(A_1)P(A_n)=P(A_n)(1-P(A_1))=P(A_n)P(A_1^c)$$

$\implies \cap_{i \in I \setminus\{n,1\}}A_i \cap A_n \cap A_1^c$ is independent and:

$$P(\cap_{i \in I \setminus\{n,1\}}A_i \cap A_n \cap A_1^c) = \Pi_{i \in I} \cap_{i \in I \setminus\{n,1\}}A_i \cap A_n \cap A_1^c$$

**Now is this the way to prove my induction or did I just babble nonsense?**

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

$P(n)$: Let $A_1,...A_n$ be independent events, then $A_1',A_2,...,A_n$ are also independent.

$P(1)$ is trivial. Let $P(n-1)$ hold. To show that $B_1=A_1',B_2=A_2,...,B_n=A_n$ are independent, we need to prove for any subset $I$ of $[n]$:

$$P(\cap_{i\in I}B_i)=\Pi_{i \in I}P(B_i).$$

As $P(n-1)$ holds and consideting the assupmtion, for all $|I| \le n-1$, the above holds. Hence, we need to prove it only for $I=[n]$, which is shown below:

$$P(A_1'\cap_{i=2}^nA_i)=P(\cap_{i=2}^nA_i)-P(A_1\cap_{i=2}^nA_i)=(1-P(A_1))P(\cap_{i=2}^nA_i)
=P(A'_1)\Pi_{i=2}^{n}P(A_i).$$